# What is the type for varchar(10) in a prepared statement query?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using PreparedStatements for my Java database work.

I am currently referring to this tutorial my MKYong: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/

For my primary key, I have a `varchar(10)` used to store Unix time. It seems in a statement like `preparedStatement.setSomething()`, I must define what `type` it is. What is the type for `varChar(10)`?

The Unix time goes something like this: 1382944400, which is something like November 8th 2013 and some time today.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29 Converts string to varchar for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `CHAR(X)` and `VARCHAR(X)` field falls in the `String` Java type.

From [`PreparedStatement#setString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Sets the designated parameter to the given Java `String` value. The driver converts this to an **`SQL VARCHAR` or `LONGVARCHAR`** value (depending on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on `VARCHAR` values) when it sends it to the database.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage you're welcome. But if I were you, I would follow [JBNizet's advises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19868740/1065197).

Comment: Your timestamp is a Java long: an 8-bytes signed integer. The [documentation for MySQL numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) shows that MySQL has the same 8-byte signed numeric type, called BIGINT. So use BIGINT. BTW, that's also the type indicated in the [javadoc of PreparedStatement.setLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks I will refer to this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what about timestamp?

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal there’s a class called `java.sql.Timestamp`. Refer to the proper javadoc for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The natural type for varchar would be String, although most of the other types would probably work fine and be converted (if you use `setObject()` at least).

But why use a varchar to store a long value? Why don't you use a number instead? That would consumer less memory, lead to a better natural sort, and would be more efficient.

Comment: That's a good question. I have a column which I set as a `Primary Key`, and that column is a 10-digit long (hence why I used varChar(10)) Unix-format date. What is the best `type` to use in that scenario? I only did varChar(length) because MySQL Workbench asked me to set a int length. I need suggestions!